# AddToAny links appear after reloading

Tags: javascript, addtoany

I am working on angular 17 project, and I need to add social links.

I was recommended to use [AddToAny](https://www.addtoany.com/) library, so my code is the following:

```html
<div class="share">
  <p>share</p>
  <!-- AddToAny BEGIN -->

  <div class="a2a_kit a2a_kit_size_32 a2a_default_style share-this">
    <a class="a2a_dd" href="https://www.addtoany.com/share"></a>
    <a class="a2a_dd a2a_button_facebook"></a>
    <a class="a2a_dd a2a_button_linkedin"></a>
    <a class="a2a_dd a2a_button_twitter"></a>
    <a class="a2a_dd a2a_button_pinterest"></a>
    <a class="a2a_dd" href="https://www.addtoany.com/share"></a>
  </div>
  <script async src="https://static.addtoany.com/menu/page.js"></script>

  <!-- AddToAny END -->
</div>
```

The problem is, that with the first page load - I don't see any social icon, but reloading the page cause them suddenly appear.

can you please tell what am I wrong with? what am I missing?

thanks a lot for every help!

Comment: Snippet works as is. If I were you I would try to switch to the `a2a.init('page')` method as seen in the [documentation](https://www.addtoany.com/buttons/customize/asynchronous_loading)

Comment: @DarkBee I see the docs, I undestand that you recommend to add onready function, but I don't see how to do this, onready to what? what is a2a_config?  can you leave an answer with code so I understand this correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Another method to apply `add2any` on links you want to share on social platforms is by using the `a2a.init('page')` call after the script is actually loaded in.

To do this you can define a custom callback function in the `a2a_config`.
After the script is loaded and the callback is called you can initialize any link you want.

[reference](https://www.addtoany.com/buttons/customize/asynchronous_loading)

```js
var a2a_config = a2a_config || {};
a2a_config.callbacks = a2a_config.callbacks || [];
a2a_config.callbacks.push({
    ready: my_addtoany_onready
});


function my_addtoany_onready() {
    console.log('-- called by add2any --');
    a2a_config.target = '.share'; // any selector can be put here to target the links you want to be shareable
    // Additional instance configs can be set here
    a2a.init('page');
}
```

```html
<a href="http://www.example.com" class="share">Example.com</a>
<script async src="https://static.addtoany.com/menu/page.js"></script>
```

---

If you don't want to display all services at once, you configure the `prioritize` property as seen [here](https://www.addtoany.com/buttons/customize/prioritize_services)

Comment: thank you for the answer , but I don't undestand what is the `a2a` object in the last line, where it comes from? and is this code good for angular too?

Comment: That's just a variable holding the instance of the `add2any` object. That's just how `add2any` works - "*is this code good for angular too*", this doesn't matter can be used on any platform as long as javascript is enabled

Comment: ok, but where do I **instantiate** this variable? (`a2a`), cause my code throws error...  "Cannot find name 'a2a'"

Comment: You don't, that variable is available (and created by `add2any`) *after* the script `https://static.addtoany.com/menu/page.js` is loaded in. Maybe you are using an addblock that is preventing add2any from loading in. Check your network tab